# Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator. (Builder function wont display MainPage())

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, navigation, builder

As soon as I press the button I get the error code "Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator." Code im using to navigate is in the RegisterPage and by the builder function should be displaying the MainPage.

```
void main() => runApp(RegisterPage());

class RegisterPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Register Your Account'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context)
                .push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => MainPage()
              ),
            );
          },
          child: Text('Sign in as guest'),
        )),
      )
    );
  }
}

  class MainPage extends StatefulWidget{
  String get title => "Cykla i stockholm";

  MapPage createState()=> MapPage();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the widget which uses the navigator (`RegisterPage`) is at the same level in the widget tree with the widget which creates the navigator(`MaterialApp`)

**SOLUTION**:
make the `RegisterPage` below `MaterialApp` in order to be able to use its `context`:

```
class RegisterPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Register Your Account'),
            centerTitle: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          ),
          body: Builder(
            builder: (ctx)=> Center(//this context here has access to Navigator
                child: RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(ctx)
                        .push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => MainPage()
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  child: Text('Sign in as guest'),
                )),
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Nothing changed.

Comment: @MikaelYousif sorry there is a typo i forgot to put ctx instead of context

Comment: Seems like it worked or maybe not, but i'm getting a new error code which is the following: "There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree."

Comment: that has nothing to do with this
that error is because you are using same tag on different hero widgets